# Serilog in ASP.NET Core - logging the EventId in its own column

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

ASP.NET Core logging has this concept of 'Log event ID',
so that we can log lines like this (from their documentation);

```
_logger.LogInformation(LoggingEvents.GET_ITEM, "Getting item {ID}", id);
```

Serilog writes this inforamtion, LoggingEvents.GET_ITEM, in the properties column

```
<property key='EventId'>
<structure type=''>
  <property key='Id'>1002</property>
</structure>
```

I've added a new column 'EventId' in the table in the database, and added this ColumnOptions to the logger

```
columnOptions.AdditionalDataColumns = new List<DataColumn>
        {
            new DataColumn {DataType = typeof(byte), ColumnName = "EventId"},
            new DataColumn {DataType = typeof(string), ColumnName = "SessionId"}
        };
```

But Serilog doesn't write anything to the database. Only when I remove this line:
`new DataColumn {DataType = typeof(byte), ColumnName = "EventId"},`
does Serilog write the line to the databse, but without the EventId column.
How can I write the event id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EventId` in ASP.NET Core isn't an integer, but rather a structure that may contain an integer, a string, (effectively) neither, or both.

https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/EventId.cs

When it reaches the SQL Server sink, it can't be converted into a numeric column, unfortunately. I think you'll need to specify the column as text for this to work.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you Nicholas, and thank you for this great library.

Comment: I tried a Destructurer but it did not work :(. Also needed to go the string way